# Difference of click event bound methods in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What are the differences between these two click event bounding methods;

```
$('#save').click(function() {
});
```

&

```
$(document).on('click', '#save', function() {
});
```

Comment: Hey lordwin, please check [ask].

Comment: The first one is bound to a specific element with the id 'save', the second one is more general and will work for any element with the class 'save'. The advantages of the second form: more than one element using the same handler and it also keeps working, for dynamically added/removed elements with the class 'save'. PS: this is javascript, not php.

Comment: RTFM: http://api.jquery.com/on/, http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: To all sorry for the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first function will target all objects in existance at initialization, and put a hook onto those. While the second way: `$(document).on(...)` will hook the option to the document, which means that if there's a new button with that id generated (*by Ajax for example*) it will also trigger that event.

Use the second option for dynamically added content.